# Display label name differently to api name using VF on page layout

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, fields

I want to display the a field label differently on a Product record. I have written the VF below. However, when I go to a Product record, it still displays as "Product Name" and not "Project Name". What am I doing wrong?

```
<apex:page standardController="Product2">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Name}" 
                label="Project Name" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>    
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apex:outputLabel` with `apex:pageBlockSectionItem`:

```
<apex:page standardController="Product2">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Project Name"/>
                    <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Name}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

`apex:pageBlockSectionItem` could be used when you'd like to add different labels to `apex:inputField` or `apex:outputField`

Comment: When I click "preview" on the code, it says "A pageBlockSection component must be contained within a pageBlock component" And then when I go to a Product 2 record I find that it hasn't changed.

Comment: then add a `apex:pageblock`, updated my answer :)